# R: Why does st_join give invalid times error?

Tags: left-join, geospatial, nearest-neighbor, r-sf

I am trying to join 2 `SpatialPointsDataFrames` by nearest neighbour analysis using `sf::st_join()`. Both files have been converted using `st_as_sf()` but when I try the join I get the error

> Error in rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), lengths(i)) : invalid 'times' argument

At this point I have tried swapping the x and y arguments, and adjusting countless variations of the arguments but nothing seems to work. I have checked the help file for `sf::st_join()`, but don't see anything about a `times` argument? So I am unsure where from and why it keeps throwing this error...

below is a sample of my data set which produces the same error using the code further down

```
> head(sf.eSPDF[[1]])
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 8 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 35.9699 ymin: -3.74514 xmax: 35.97065 ymax: -3.74474
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  TIME                ELEVATION LATITUDE LONGITUDE DATE       V1                  V2                  Survey            geometry
  <dttm>              <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl> <date>     <dttm>              <dttm>               <dbl>         <POINT [°]>
1 2012-01-20 07:26:05 1018 m       -3.74      36.0 2012-01-20 2012-01-20 00:00:00 2012-01-31 00:00:00      1 (35.97047 -3.74474)
2 2012-01-20 07:27:35 1018 m       -3.74      36.0 2012-01-20 2012-01-20 00:00:00 2012-01-31 00:00:00      1 (35.97057 -3.74486)
3 2012-01-20 07:27:39 1019 m       -3.74      36.0 2012-01-20 2012-01-20 00:00:00 2012-01-31 00:00:00      1  (35.9706 -3.74489)
4 2012-01-20 07:27:47 1020 m       -3.74      36.0 2012-01-20 2012-01-20 00:00:00 2012-01-31 00:00:00      1 (35.97065 -3.74489)
5 2012-01-20 07:28:05 1020 m       -3.74      36.0 2012-01-20 2012-01-20 00:00:00 2012-01-31 00:00:00      1 (35.97035 -3.74498)
6 2012-01-20 07:28:26 1019 m       -3.75      36.0 2012-01-20 2012-01-20 00:00:00 2012-01-31 00:00:00      1  (35.9699 -3.74514)
```

```
> head(sf.plt.centr)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 35.75955 ymin: -3.91594 xmax: 36.0933 ymax: -3.401
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
    PairID                  geometry
1        1   POINT (36.0933 -3.6731)
42      92 POINT (36.02593 -3.91594)
83     215 POINT (36.06496 -3.75837)
124    225   POINT (35.83156 -3.401)
165    251 POINT (35.75955 -3.54388)
206      2 POINT (36.08752 -3.69128)
```

Below is the code that I am using to check for working solutions

```
sf.eSPDF<-lapply(eSPDF, function(x){
  st_as_sf(as(x, "SpatialPointsDataFrame"))
})


sf.plt.centr<-st_as_sf(as(plt.centr, "SpatialPointsDataFrame"))

x1<-head(sf.eSPDF[[1]])
x2<-head(sf.plt.centr)

check<-st_join(x1, x2, join=st_nn, maxdist = Inf, returnDist = T, progress = TRUE)
```

As you can see, the file I want to join to is an object within a list. All objects within that list have identical structure to the example given. Eventually I want to get a code that joins the `sf.plt.centr` file to each of the files within the list. Something like...

```
big.join<-lapply(sf.eSPDF, function(x){
  st_join('['(x), sf.plt.centr, st_nn, maxdist = Inf, returnDist = T, progress = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Not sure this will help, but what happens when you try this 
```x1<-head(sf.eSPDF[[1]]) %>% tibble() %>% mutate(geometry = geometry %>% st_sfc(crs=4326) %>% st_sf(crs=4326))
x2<-head(sf.plt.centr) %>% tibble() %>% mutate(geometry = geometry %>% st_sfc(crs=4326) %>% st_sf(crs=4326))

check<-st_join(x1, x2, join=st_nn, maxdist = Inf, returnDist = T, progress = TRUE)```